# Styling regression tables in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to style the regression table in below format. The part is a bit challenging is dealing with NA in the final output...How do I remove them?

```
library(gtsummary)
library(stringr)

# build logistic regression model
m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

tbl_m1 <- tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE)

# Format the output inf the form OR (conf.low, conf.high)

tbl_m1$table_body <- tbl_m1$table_body %>%
  mutate(
    estimate = round(estimate, 1),
    conf.low = round(conf.low, 1),
    conf.high = round(conf.high, 1),
    #estimate = ifelse(is.na(estimate), "", estimate),
    ci = str_glue("{estimate}", " (", "{conf.low}, {conf.high}", ")") )

tbl_m1 %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**",
                          ci = "**COR**") %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = c("ci")) %>%
  modify_column_hide(c(estimate, p.value))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.2'

# build logistic regression model
m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE, estimate_fun = \(x) style_number(x, digits = 1)) |> 
  modify_column_merge(pattern = "{estimate} ({ci})", rows = !is.na(estimate)) |> 
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**", estimate = "**COR**") |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on StackOverflow
```

| **Variable** | **COR** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 1.0 (1.0, 1.0) | 0.091 |
| T Stage |  |  |
| T1 | — |  |
| T2 | 0.6 (0.2, 1.4) | 0.2 |
| T3 | 0.9 (0.4, 2.3) | 0.9 |
| T4 | 0.8 (0.3, 1.9) | 0.6 |

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Cleaner and shorter. I followed a very long route! Many thanks